# Mongo DB migration with less downtime

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My task is migrate mongodb ( 10 DBS ) from source to destination with less time.

1. We find the most realistic approach, migrate from cloud to onprim restore full backup from source and restore
2. After restore use mongodump oplog logbackup every 30 mins all databases and restore on destination , I don’t know how to take timestamp and Timestamp(1470923942, 2) how to automate.
3. It will apply the same until it reaches to the actual downtime for cutover, we want to automate dump & restore in crontab until cutover

Looking for your suggestions and thoughts to meet my requirement.

thank you in advance .

Looking for suggestions & review my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but what I would do if I had to migrate MongoDB from location X to Y, is to create a new cluster on Y, mark all the nodes on Y as secondary and add them to the X cluster, let all the connections drain, then mark any node on Y as primary, let the connections drain, kill X.

You will need to have some kind of secure connection between X and Y (probably a VPN).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don’t know when is my cutover so that I need to create cron make it sync, to meet the requirement, below are my thoughts.

1. Take FULL backup from X ( source ) and restore Y ( destination )
2. Example if I take mongodump 10:00 AM system time , to get bsontime I need to create basondump and get the last trx Timestamp(1669619066, 1) this last time use for next mondodump script 10.05 AM system time so on, it was dependent on last mondodump.
3. Take incremental backup every 5 mins using oplog for all DBs  and restore